# Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint

I'm trying to open the official redux todos example project by

```
git clone https://github.com/reduxjs/redux
cd redux/examples/todos
npm install && npm start
```

but it gives me this error

```
Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from.
Referenced from: /home/myUserName/redux/.eslintrc.js
```

When I refresh I can see the app for less than a second and then the error appears again.

I tried `yarn install && yarn start` after cloning, but no difference.
I also tried `yarn add eslint-config-react-app`, still no difference.

Answer (score -2):

I was exactly in the same situation.
Create a file ".env" in your folder and add a line

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

to ".env". It worked for me.

It's not really ideal to skip checking.
But it should be ok now: we are trying to run an example anyway.

Comment: `~/Desktop/redux/examples/todos$ cat .env`
Output: `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`
Did it, but unfortunately still not working for me.

Comment: Doesn't prevent it from crashing npm run build.